# Assignment operation from constant value in Kotlin not working

Tags: android, kotlin, constants, variable-assignment

In the ViewModel of my Android app built with `Kotlin`, The method shown below sets the state to the values passed in to it. But if the calling code passes in a `String` constant, it is not set to the constant's value. Instead, it is set to an empty string. In the example below, passing in a `ZERO_STRING` constant actually assigns an empty string `""`. How can I pass in a constant and still make this work?

**Constants File**

```
ZERO_STRING = "0"
ITEM_QUANTITY_STRING = "ItemQuantity"
```

**Method in ViewModel**

```
private val _shoppingListItemState = MutableLiveData(
    savedStateHandle.get<ShoppingListItem>("shoppinglistitem")
        ?: ShoppingListItem()
)

override val shoppingListItemState: LiveData<ShoppingListItem>
        get() = _shoppingListItemState

override fun setStateValue(stateToEdit: String, stateValue: Any?) {
   var itemToUpdate = _shoppingListItemState.value!!

when(stateToEdit) {
   ITEM_QUANTITY_STRING -> itemToUpdate = itemToUpdate.copy(quantity = stateValue.toString())
}
   _shoppingListItemState.value = itemToUpdate
}
```

```
//This works
setStateValue(ITEM_QUANTITY_STRING, "0")

//This does not work. It assigns "" instead of "0"
setStateValue(ITEM_QUANTITY_STRING, ZERO_STRING)
```

Comment: I have tried this,, this seems to be fine. Can you try like this `setStateValue(ITEM_QUANTITY_STRING, "0")` from onCreate(). and just comment all the code in this function. just print log  as `Log.d("MyTag", "setStateValue: $stateToEdit - $stateValue")`. then see, if results are correct or not

Comment: What exactly is the "Constants File"?

Comment: @SohaibAhmed I think I know the source of the bug. Let me see if that's the problem. Will report back.

Comment: @Sweeper It's just a Kotlin file with all the constants in the application.

Comment: Alright, Good luck

Comment: @SohaibAhmed I reset all the `ZERO_STRING` references back to `"0"` and only used the constant in one location, and it is still assigning an empty string instead of `"0"`. So maybe something is wrong with the declaration of the data class property in the ViewModel class or in the `setStateValue()`? It's declared as follows: `private val _shoppingListItemState = MutableLiveData(savedStateHandle.get<ShoppingListItem("shoppinglistitem") ?: ShoppingListItem())`

Comment: I found the source of the bug. In the constants file, I set the ZERO_STRING value to "" instead of "0". This is a classic example of the risks of working with hard coded strings.

Comment: If you can assign to `ITEM_QUANTITY_STRING`, how is it a constant?

Comment: @gidds You mean in the constants file? How else are you going to assign a value to a constant?  If you mean what I think you mean, I'm not assigning a value to `ITEM_QUANTITY_STRING` nor `ZERO_STRING` I'm simply passing those values to `setStateValue()` so that the appropriate state can be set to the string represented by `ZERO_STRING`.

Comment: @RajNarayanan Then perhaps you could edit the question title to make it a little less misleading? (And maybe the question text, to clarify what the code is doing? For example, what is `setStateValue()`? If it's specific to a domain such as Android, that could be added to the tags.)

Comment: @gidds Suggested edits have been made. Thanks.

Comment: @RajNarayanan Thank you! Posterity will be that bit less confused :-)